# Multidimensional array prototype error in C

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, function-prototypes

I am having some trouble with the following piece of code.
It is to make a function to copy the contents of one multidimensional array to another.
The code is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void copyarray(int ros,int cos,double ard[][cos] ,double arf[][cos]);
int main(){
    int rows,columns;
    printf("Enter number of rows\n ");
    scanf("%d",&rows);
    printf("Enter number of columns\n");
    scanf("%d",&columns);
    double ar[rows][columns];
    double ar1[rows][columns];
    printf("Enter the elements ");
    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
      scanf("%lf",&ar[i][j]);
  }
    }
    printf("The 2d array is :\n");  

    for(int i=0;i<rows;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<columns;j++){
            printf("%lf ",ar[i][j]);        
  }
  printf("\n");
    }
    copyarray(rows,columns,ar,ar1); 
    return 0;
}

void copyarray(int r,int c,double ar[r][c],double arr1[r][c]){  
    for(int j=0;j<r;j++){
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      arr1[j][i]=ar[j][i];
  }
    }
    printf("The new array has the following elements:\n");
    for(int j=0;j<r;j++){
  for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
      printf("%lf ",arr1[j][i]);
  }
  printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

"use of parameter 'cos' outside function body"

Could someone help me out with this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have

```
void copyarray(int ros,int cos,double ard[][cos] ,double arf[][cos]);
```

Which is

```
type function_name(type arg_name_1,
                   type arg_name_2,
                   type array_name_1[][arg_name_2],
                   type array_name_2[][arg_name_2]);
```

Prior to C99, you cannot use an argument (in this case, `arg_name_2`) inside the function declaration. The error is referring to the use of it in `array_name_2[][arg_name_2]` as being "outside the function body".

However, as stated by HostileFork, you can do this if you're using a compiler that adheres to the C99 standard (or later).

Comment: Note that [C99 allows the usage of arguments as array bounds](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html).

Comment: So I should just try compiling it in a compiler which supports the C99 standard?

Comment: Would it hurt to try that?

Answer (score 0):

you have double `ard[][cos], double arf[][cos]`

you need `double *ard, double *arf`

because the c language is never an array is passed by value, passed only by the link

you can pass a structure by value, but that's another story

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fill(int *a)
{
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                         a[i * 10 + j] = i + j;
                }
        }
}
void print(int *a)
{
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                        printf("%2d ", a[i * 10 + j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int arr[10][10];
        fill(&arr[0][0]);
        print(&arr[0][0]);
        return 0;
}
```

may not be very pretty, but it becomes clear what actually makes the compiler

Comment: No, what the OP has written is correct, as long as they're using a compiler that supports VLAs.  In no case would an expression of type `T [n][m]` decay to type `T *`; it would decay to type `T (*)[m]`.